# Can a flow graph with integer capacities have an edge with a non-integer flow in its maximum flow?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, ford-fulkerson

Restating the problem a bit: We have a flow graph, G, with integer capacities. Can we find a maximum flow where for at least one of the edges, e, we have f(e) equal to a non-integer?

The first time I tried this I kind of glossed over it and thought that this violated the Integrality Theorem and therefore that it was false, but reading it carefully after makes it clear that it does not break any rules. Apparently it is true.

I've been trying to draw up a simple example to get a visualization, but I can't seem to come up with anything. Can anyone show me an example flow graph where this works?

Comment: Are you aware of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem ?

Comment: Or wait, are you asking if such a flow exists? Of course, if you have multiple outgoing edges from a vertex and their total capacity is greater than the incoming capacity, you can divide the flow in any way you like. But there is no need to use non-integer flows.

Comment: Ah geez, it's so obvious now. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is possible for a maxflow to have non-integer flows on edges with graphs having all integer capacities. Refer to the image. The values in boxes are the flows and the numbers without boxes are capacities.

[image: Flow network]

PS : Remember that a graph with integer capacities will always have a integer maxflow value. But it does not rule out the possibility of max flow with non-integer flows on edges.

Comment: @Maximus Hermius, if you think this answer this correct, can you accept it.

Answer (score 1):

By applying the Ford Fulkerson algorithm, all flow values and all residual capacities remain integer throughout the execution. This means that there exist at least one flow only with integer components.

Answer (score -1):

One thing I know is it does not terminate yet converge to some input of irrational number.